# Ran BNCert on Lightsail Wordpress to enable HTTPS, now getting too many redirects

Tags: wordpress, bitnami, amazon-lightsail, lightsail-container-service

Ran BNCERT tool on my Lightsail wordpress but now the site is not available and provides a too many redirects error. Domain: kofcuxbridge.ca

- I went to /opt/bitnami/apache/conf and renamed existing httpd.conf to httpd.conf.back and renamed the backup to httpd.conf
- I went to /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami and renamed bitnami.conf to bitnami.conf.back and renamed the backup to bitnami.conf

after this I restarted the server as suggested on a different thread. I am still getting an error that there are too many redirects.

Please help I am so frustrated!!

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions to try:

1. Use another browser (in incognito mode preferrably). Sometimes redirect issues are localized and may only be affecting your particular browser.
2. Clear your cookies (kind of an obvious one but it's low-hanging fruit :) ).
3. Disable your plugins one by one until you find out which one is causing the problem. Start with ones that might be used to configure SSL, security plugins for example.

In my case (same setup as OP, Bitnami WordPress on Amazon Lightsail) it turned out to be a membership plugin (Paid Memberships Pro) that was the culprit. I had enabled the "Force SSL" option in the payment Gateway Settings and this apparently causing the infinite redirection loop. Disabling it fixed the problem right away. Given this issue started after you ran the bncert-tool, my guess is you also enabled redirects from http to https.